# jquery last() for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a markup like this

```
    <ul class = "main_nav">
    <li>
        <ul class = "sub_menu">
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>world</li>
            <li>English</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class = "sub_menu">
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>world</li>
            <li>English</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class = "sub_menu">
            <li>hello</li>
            <li>world</li>
            <li>English</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I have given `border bottom` each `li` inside `sub_menu`,
but it is coming all the lis I dont want to see border bottom for last one so I have used 
jquery script like this:

```
$('.sub_menu > li').last().css('border', '0');
```

but it is effective for only last one.
How can I remove border-bottom for last `li` of each section

Comment: Just do it in CSS, no jQuery needed

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.sub_menu > li:last-child').css('border', '0');
```

The `:last-child` pseudo-element selects the last element within each parent-child group, rather than the last of all the elements matched.

Comment: One wouldn't even need jQuery for this. ;)

Answer (score 2):

No need for jquery just use the :last-child selector in your CSS to turn off the border on the last element

```
.sub_menu > li {
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
}

.sub_menu > li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```

edit: as Praveen commented, `:last-child` isn't supported by IE8 only `:first-child`

So you could always just add a `.last` class to the last item in each submenu and use this CSS rule instead of the one above with the :last-child pseudo selector

```
<li class='last'>English</li>

.sub_menu > li.last {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS is probably the better option as this seems to be something the OP doesn't need to be dynamic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sub_menu').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li:last').css('border','0');
});
```

There. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.sub_menu').each(function() {
    $(this).find('li').last().css('border', '0');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LTcDF/)**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `.each()` function?

```
$( ".sub_menu" ).each( function() {
    $( this ).children( "li" ).last().css( 'border', '0' );
} );
```

You can actually do the same using different way:

```
$( ".sub_menu > li:last-child " ).css( 'border', '0' );
```

Also, in CSS:

```
.sub_menu > li:last-child {border: 0;}
```

**Note:** The CSS method doesn't work in IE 8 and below.

Comment: this will affect everything at the ul level (rather than individual li's)

Comment: @smerny Thanks, am half asleep! :P